# AFNetworking 3.0 redirect lost header

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

I have used **setTaskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionBlock** on **AFHTTPSessionManager**, but after redirection, I always got 401 error, **Authentication credentials were not provided.** I've tried to send request to the endpoint without redirection, it works. But with redirection, seems the header is lost after redirecting. I have tried also to add header in **AFHTTPSessionManager** block, but still no luck.

```
[self.sessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token %@", authToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[self.sessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:self.userAgentInfo forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[self.sessionManager setTaskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionBlock:^NSURLRequest * _Nonnull(NSURLSession * _Nonnull session, NSURLSessionTask * _Nonnull task, NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request) {
    NSLog(@"%@", request.URL);
    return request; 
}];


[self.sessionManager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@path/", self.host]
                parameters:nil
                  progress:nil
                   success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
```

Comment: Just curious, do you have control of the server doing the redirection?

Comment: @Adam, yes, I've tried to call the same endpoint in another app with Alarmofire(also with redirection), it works.

Comment: What type of redirection are you doing? I've found it helpful to do a 307/308 instead of a 301/302 with AFNetworking and skip the `setTaskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionBlock` entirely

Comment: @Adam, it's 301/302, do you have any idea about doing that with AFNetworking? doing 307/308 is the only solution?

Comment: What I'm suggesting has nothing to do with AFNetworking - other than removing your `setTaskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionBlock` - it has to do with configuring your server (or whatever is issuing the redirect) to issue 307/308 response codes instead of 301/302s.

Comment: @Adam thank you very much for your suggestion. I'll have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your code suggestions you're using an operation manager, so you can just set the credential property:

```
self.operationManager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:...];
self.operationManager.credential = [[NSURLCredential alloc] initWithUser:USERNAME password:PASSWORD persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];
```

Comment: but I've already logged in this situation, just need to set the token and userInfo in the request

Answer (score 0):

After having struggled few hours, found solution:

```
[self.sessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token %@", authToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[self.sessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:self.userAgentInfo forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[self.sessionManager setTaskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionBlock:^NSURLRequest * _Nonnull(NSURLSession * _Nonnull session, NSURLSessionTask * _Nonnull task, NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request) {
    NSLog(@"%@", request.URL);
    NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:request.URL];
    [newRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token %@", authToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [newRequest setValue:self.userAgentInfo forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    return newRequest;
}];

[self.sessionManager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@paths/", self.host]
                parameters:nil
                  progress:nil
                   success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying over all the http request headers of the original request into the new/current request in the setTaskWillPerformHTTPRedirectBlock, does the trick for me.

It looks like that in Swift:

```
    // copy original request headers to current request when following HTTP redirect
    manager.setTaskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionBlock { (session, task, response, request) -> URLRequest? in
        var newRequest = request
        task.originalRequest?.allHTTPHeaderFields?.forEach({ (arg) in
            let (key, value) = arg
            newRequest.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        })
        return newRequest
    }
```